# Web Page ruuning but nothing showing

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I recently made a project on Angular JS in Visual Studio,it was working fine but suddenly its starting strange behavior. When I do run project the static controls looks but data not showing on browser. Also browser keeps loading continuously. Neither I can do right click on browser nor I can click on any control.
What may be the reason?

Comment: Can you give further details, for example the console log? And have you used apply() or digest() functions? Their improper use can cause infinite loops too.

Comment: On page inspector after debugging I found this error- **Maximum call stack size exceeded** And I did not used any apply() or digest() function